# How to set minimum and maximum values for Angular reactive form validation?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6

We have an Angular reactive form which has a birthday, month and years field. Here is the code:

```
 private buildSignupForm() {
    this.SignupForm = this.fb.group({
      bday: [null, [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(2)]],
      bmonth: [null, [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(2)]],
      byear: [null, [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(4), Validators.minLength(4)]],
      city: [null, [Validators.required, Validators.pattern('[a-zA-Z ]*')]],
    });
    this.SignupForm.setValidators(this.minimumAge(18));
  }
}
```

How can I set birthday value minimum 01 maximum 31?
And month: minimum 01 maximum 12?
Year: minimum 1950 and max 2000 e.g.?

Answer (score 9):

You can use [Validators.max](https://angular.io/api/forms/Validators#max) and [Validators.min](https://angular.io/api/forms/Validators#min) for that purpose.

```
 private buildSignupForm() {
    this.SignupForm = this.fb.group({
      bday: [null, [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(2), Validators.max(31), Validators.min(1)]],
      bmonth: [null, [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(2), Validators.max(12), Validators.min(1)]],
      byear: [null, [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(4), Validators.minLength(4),Validators.max(2000), Validators.min(1950)]],
      city: [null, [Validators.required, Validators.pattern('[a-zA-Z ]*')]],
    });
    this.SignupForm.setValidators(this.minimumAge(18));
  }
}
```

You can manually check for the triggering of the min/max validators by accessing the `errors` property on your FormGroup.

```
console.log(this.SignupForm['controls']['bday'].errors.min); 
console.log(this.SignupForm['controls']['bday'].errors.max);
// prints true or false
```

And on your component.html, you can include some kind of validation message that is shown/hidden conditionally.

```
<div class="feedback" *ngIf="SignupForm['controls']['bday'].errors?.min">Minimum date is 1.</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. But will the month accept 01 as well?

Comment: @NewTechLover Yes, as long as the input value is interpreted as a number. You can test it out if you want!

Comment: Also, I have made some changes on the last 2 blocks of code as we have specify the specific form control in order to access the validator output